# Ability to set CompletedDateTime on Task object while loading tasks from data loader

Tags: data-loader, tasks, data-migration, audit-fields

We are trying to load tasks using data loader, where curtains tasks need to be loaded in 'Completed' status, we have observed if a tasks get's loaded with 'Completed' date the System is automatically setting standard 'CompletedDateTime' date fields as date on when task is loaded with 'Completed' status, similar to CreatedDate.

Is there a way we can set a different date into CompletedDateTime with Data loader, I have enabled permission to set audit fields as well, but only created date is available with this permission but not CompletedDateTime.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm), you cannot set the value of `CompletedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort them, you can actually do them by Due Date.. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?
id=sf.activitytimeline_sorting_past_activities_task.htm&language=en_US&type=5

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/205172)